# SQLAlchemy query where one row may not exist

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy

I'm implementing some search functionality for a database of companies and their subsidiaries. For each company there may be multiple subsidiaries or none. Each subsidiary has a company_id column that links it to the id column of the parent company table.

Here is an example of how searching for a company by name:

```
def search_by_company_name(name):
    company_search = session.query(Company.name).filter(Company.name.like('%{}%'.format(name)))
    return company_search.all()
```

What I want is to be able to query a company by searching for not only its name but also the names of any subsidiaries that might share a similar name. What I have right now is:

```
def search_by_company_and_subsidiary_name(name):
    company_search = session.query(Company.name).filter(Company.name.like('%{}%'.format(name)) | Subsidiary.name.like('%{}%'.format(name)))
    search_results = company_search.filter(Company.id == Subsidiary.company_id)
    return search_results.all()
```

The problem with my approach is that if there are no subsidiaries for a certain parent company, then the query returns nothing, even if the name search matches to a row in the Company table.

For example:

```
search_by_company_name('accenture')
>>> [('Accenture',)]
```

However

```
search_by_company_and_subsidiary_name('accenture')
>>> []
```

I'm sure that the second function is returning [] because there are no subsidiaries for Accenture in my database, so the predicate `.filter(Subsidiary.company_id == Company.id)` is essentially removing any results already found in the Company table. I'm thinking the solution might be to do something like a left join, but I haven't had any luck after troubleshooting for a while.

Is there a good way to do a query like this in SQLAlchemy that will still return all the rows found in a certain table when there are no matching rows in the Subsidiary table for a given company?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider implementing an outerjoin rather than a strict filter condition, e.g. something along the lines of:

```
def search_by_company_and_subsidiary_name(name):
    return session.query(Company)
                  .outerjoin(Subsidiary, Company.id == Subsidiary.company_id)
                  .filter(Company.name.like('%{}%'.format(name)) | Subsidiary.name.like('%{}%'.format(name)))
                  .all()
```

Comment: After a bit more digging, that's actually exactly what I ended up doing, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Good to read Zach. Would appreciate if you could accept the answer. :)